# Assigning/Initializing references in function args

Tags: c++

I am from C background and trying to understand what this means:

```
void f(const string &x = "hello") {
}
```

Is x set to a default value if nothing is passed in?
Where does "hello" reside?

Comment: You might be interested in something like [Accelerated C++](http://www.informit.com/store/accelerated-c-plus-plus-practical-programming-by-example-9780201703535).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your parameter (`x`) is created/initialized in the context of the calling function. The string literal `"hello" has static storage duration.

The standard doesn't specify the form of memory in which either of those is stored, but in a typical case, the string literal will reside in some memory that's initialized directly from data in the executable file, and `x` will be created on the stack (with the address of the literal passed to initialize it if you don't pass something else in its place).

Answer (score 2):

It's called default parameters, which you will learn if you visit [this link](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/77-default-parameters/).

> A default parameter is a function parameter that has a default value
>   provided to it. If the user does not supply a value for this
>   parameter, the default value will be used. If the user does supply a
>   value for the default parameter, the user-supplied value is used.

So, if you call `f` like this -

```
f();
```

then `x` will contain `hello`, but if you call it like this -

```
f("test");
```

then `x` will contain `test`.

Comment: @Prime: Well, that was a typo. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

That parameter declaration is equivalent to the following more explicit one

```
void f(const string &x = string("hello"))
```

You are correct: the part after the `=` (so called *default argument*) is used when the function is called without an explicit argument, as in

```
f();
```

In that case a temporary object of `string` type is constructed from `"hello"` initializer and then used as an initializer for reference `x`. The construction of that temporary is performed in the context of the calling code, which means that the above call is equivalent to

```
f(string("hello"));
```

To answer your question about `"hello"`: `"hello"` is a string literal which has static storage duration (i.e. it resides in static memory, just like in C). But again, note that in this example it is not `"hello"` itself that is used as an initializer for the reference. In this case the compiler will implicitly create a short-lived nameless temporary `string` object for that purpose, as explicitly spelled out in my examples above.